# Confusion matrix sklearn bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I was doing a test with `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` to see what happen if in the prediction array there is a class which is not in the labels and mapping arrays.
My code is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm

a = ["positive\n", "positive\n", "negative\n", "positive\n", "negative\n"]
b = ["negative\n", "negative\n", "don't\n", "negative\n", "negative\n"]
m = ["positive\n", "negative\n"]
c = cm(a, b, m)
TN, FP, FN, TP = c.ravel()

print(c)
print("")
print("{} {} {} {}\n".format(TN, FP, FN, TP))
```

The ouput is:

```
[[0 3]
 [0 1]]

0 3 0 1
```

So the class `don't` is skipped.

---

But if you look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for the version `v0.21.2` which is the one I installed the `ravel()` method "should" output the values of the confusion matrix as I wrote: TN, FP, FN, TP. The output of my `print` is different. It seems that the real ouput of `ravel()` is flipped: TP, FN, FP, TN. Is my thought right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug. You have defined labels:

```
m = ["positive\n", "negative\n"]
```

therefore `"positive\n"` is negative and `"negative\n"` is positive. And the result meets your specification.

If you modify `m` this way:

```
m = ["negative\n", "positive\n"]
```

you will get:

```
1 0 3 0
```

for `TN, FP, FN, TP`, respectively.

Comment: so in the case of binary a classification the first class in the mapping array must be the "negative" class to get the `ravel()` results correct, otherwise I must swap the return values? But it's the same result at the end, right?

Comment: There is nothing right or wrong per se. To understand the process, build a matrix where rows are true classes and columns are predicted classes. Then, fill up the matrix with respect to predicted and true values. And you get the result.